# How to display more than one movie on the screen rather than just displaying one movie from the moviesDB api in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, api, react-native

I am trying to extract all the "original_title" from the array of objects that I am getting back from the api call and display them in the flatlist. I am using react native.  I try to console.log the api data and can see that I am in fact an array of objects which has the "original_title" data that I want. However, it seems I can only get one at a time. I want to know how I can extract the multiple "original_title" from the array of objects. Please see my code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const HomeScreen =()=> {
    const API_KEY1="hidden";
    const API_KEY2="hidden";
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);


    useEffect(()=> {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY2}`);
            setMovies([response.data]);
            console.log("RESPONSE.DATA!!!!" ,response.data)
            console.log("RESPONSE.DATA.Results[0]!!!!" ,response.data.results[0])
        }

        fetchData();

    }, [])


    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <FlatList data={movies} renderItem={({item})=> {
                return <Text>{[item.results.title]}</Text>
            }}/>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
})

export default HomeScreen;
```

[image]

console.log(response.data)
console.log(response.data.results[0])

[image]

I just want to know how I can extract all those "original_title" info and output it in the flatlist. Thanks!

Comment: your Question is too confusing please add more description to it and clarify that what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that You are setting the state of movies to [response.data]. Which equals to an array with one element - the whole response You are getting from the server. Instead try

```
setMovies(response.data.results)
```

and in your render function

```
return <Text>{item.original_title}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it